# I want to select a random XPath from the defined Array

Tags: node.js, automation, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

```
editMethod(){
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() *4) + 1);

var xPath_arr= [

    '//android.widget.RadioButton[@text="seat1"]',
    '//android.widget.RadioButton[@text="seat2"]',
    '//android.widget.RadioButton[@text="seat3"]',
    '//android.widget.RadioButton[@text="Notselected"]',
    ]

    xPath_arr[num]

}

Then calling in another function like this

selectseat(){

this.editmethod();
this.doneBtn.click();

}
```

tried different method but received different errors  like

**but its not working**

**TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined**

Comment: Are you receiving a line for the error? Where is doneBtn defined?

Comment: @MikeCollins  doneBtn is done button and XPath is defined in the selectors.
the error is on line this.editmethod();

Comment: Looks like you need to use `editMethod` rather than `editmethod` in your call.

Comment: Nope, that is okay. I already changed that. but it's still not working.. but never mind I use switch statement and it's working perfectly according to my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
const editMethod = () => {
    let num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    console.log(num)
    let xPath_arr = [
        '//android.widget.RadioButton[@text="seat1"]',
        '//android.widget.RadioButton[@text="seat2"]',
        '//android.widget.RadioButton[@text="seat3"]',
        '//android.widget.RadioButton[@text="Notselected"]',
    ]
    return xPath_arr[num];
}

// Then calling in another function like this

const selectseat =() => {

    let seatElement = editMethod();
    console.log(locator);

}

selectseat();
```

Note:

Math.random() * 3 it should be because your array contains 4 elements only.